# Why don't I have have permission to add Project Work Items in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am the owner of an Organization and the project within that organization, but I am not able to see the Add button for work types.

What permission needs to be set for me to have this ability?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to edit a base process. You have to create a child process first: [Create and manage inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the built-in process types. You must first create an inherited template. You can edit that and then switch the process type of your project.